# cant run a zend controller/action

Tags: php, zend-framework

I typed this:

```
http://localhost/dev.gamenomad.com/Index
```

and I have got this controller in my zend project:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->pageTitle = "About GameNomad";
}
```

Basically, the action controller doesnt come up.

I get this output:

```
Object not found!
```

> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404 localhost 02/13/12 14:59:19 Apache/2.2.21 (Win32)
>   mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

and when I type: http://localhost/dev.gamenomad.com/

I get this:

> Index of /dev.gamenomad.com

```
Parent Directory
.zfproject.xml
application/
docs/
library/
nbproject/
public/
tests/
```

Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 Server at localhost Port 80

Why do I get this and what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is `/dev.gamenomad.com` supposed to be?

Comment: I think it is considered a controller name by Zend. The real site is `localhost`.

Comment: dammit.. how do I restructure teh whole thing to mak eit work

Comment: Do I have to resort to virtual host?

Comment: Add `resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/dev.gamenomad.com"` to your application.ini and see if that helps. Also, AFAIR, your document root should be set to the `public` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is sort of miss-configuration done by you. Since you get directory index when you access the URL http://localhost/dev.gamenomad.com/ you may try following URL to run your zend action.

http://localhost/dev.gamenomad.com/public/index/

Check this.

Note:

it's OK since this is your localhost. When you put things on live make sure you OFF directory index and people can only access to the `public` directory via HTTP requests.

Comment: First tell me whether it is working or not? Then I will try to explain how it is happening.

Comment: OK Great. In Zend framework you basically have 3 main directories application, library and public. The public is the directory which has index.php file. The whole web site control via this file. So to execute you have to locate to that file first as http://localhost/dev.gamenomad.com/public/ Then the index.php file will execute given controller/action/params. Hope you understand. Also please mark as correct answer if you think it is.